# How to forbid children for a React component with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component for which I expect no children to be passed to it. Can I enforce it with typescript?

Comment: Yes. If you define a component without accepting props in its parameters, its automatically enforced not to accept props.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the component's props like this:

```js
type ComponentProps = {
  children?: undefined;
}
```

Comment: This will allow the following: `<MyComponent>{undefined}</MyComponent>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
type MyComponentProps = {
  children?: never;
}
```

**Valid cases:**

- `<MyComponent />`

**Invalid cases:**

- `<MyComponent>{undefined}</MyComponent>`
- `<MyComponent>{'foobar'}</MyComponent>`
- `<MyComponent>foobar</MyComponent>`
- `<MyComponent><>foobar</></MyComponent>`
- `<MyComponent><br /></MyComponent>`
- `<MyComponent><b>foobar</b></MyComponent>`
- `<MyComponent><Foo /></MyComponent>`